# Invalid regular expression: /(/: Unterminated group

Tags: regex

I want to create a function that removes all unwanted characters from a text. This is what I came up with, but it doesn´t work:

```
var invalid = "^°\"§%()[]{}=\\?´`'#<>|,;.:-+_";

for (var n = 0; n < invalid.length; n++) 
{
   var r = new RegExp(invalid[n],"g");
   toCheck.replace(r,"");
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to loop through invalid characters. Just use regex like this:

```
var invalid = /[°"§%()\[\]{}=\\?´`'#<>|,;.:+_-]+/g;
var repl = toCheck.replace(invalid, "");
```

Comment: i'm getting this error searching for a wordbreak character. any ideas?:

`var wordbreaker="``1234567890~!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]{};':\",.<>/?\\| ";
wordbreaker.search(some_char);`

Comment: @jaya: Keep unescaped hyphen at first or last place in character class.